# Haven't or hadn't

Tags: present-perfect, past-perfect

It's 
1.Back  to the old days when I haven't cut my bangs 
Or
2.Back to the old days when I hadn't cut my bangs

Answer (score 1):

"Hadn't".  There are two past times involved.  One is the old days and the "when" that refers to this past time -- that corresponds to the past tense of "had".  The other past time is the span of time previous to the old days during which you still had uncut bangs -- this corresponds to the "have" part of "had".  So, there's a span of time ("have") that preceded a previous time (past tense of "have") during which span you didn't cut your hair.

(I hope I have that straight.)

The interpretation of past perfects in English was described by Hans Reichenbach in his text **Introduction to Symbolic Logic** and elaborated by James McCawley in an article "Time and Tense in English", with the latter incorporated into McCawley's book **The Syntactic Phenomena of English**.